# is there a tool to dump a database schema (SQL DDL) to XML?

Tags: sql, xml, database, postgresql, ddl

I'm looking to automatically generate an XML version of a database schema from SQL (Postgres) DDL.

Are there any tools to help with getting from the DDL to XML?

[xml2ddl](http://xml2ddl.berlios.de/) claims to do this, but it fails to connect and seems unsupported since 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `table_to_xmlschema` etc.; see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING.

Comment: This would be perfect except that it requires Postgres to be configured using --with-libxml, unfortunately no the case with Ubuntu's Postgres. I don't really wan't compile my own Postgres and replace my running instance to get this functionality.

Comment: @Jamie Bullock: Ubuntu's PostgreSQL package is certainly built with `--with-libxml`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Seems my call syntax was wrong. Turns out that table_to_xmlschema() gives me exactly what I want with minimum fuss.

Answer (score 1):

Things that spring immediately to my mind:

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)
[Schemaspy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/)
[SQL Workbench's WbSchemaReport](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-schema-report)

They don't use a DDL (SQL) script as input but require a database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also researched [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/)?

Comment: I never needed to go any further than Postgres' table_to_xmlschema() because that does exactly what I need.